# Unable to extract text from a specific span tag using Python's Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

I am currently scraping [this website](https://www.sosubaru.com/new-inventory/index.htm?start=0) to build a car dataset and I have an equation built to loop through each page of the website while scraping. However, I am unable to extract the text I need to make this work.

The below code snippet is the tag that I am trying to scrape. I need to get the number of vehicles on the site.

```
<span class="d-none d-sm-inline">166 Vehicles</span>
```

[This image shows the site's element that I am trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPtZi.png)

Below is my code that I am using to scrape that element:

```py
# Packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
print("Started web scrape...")
    
limit = 10
start = 0 #increment by limit
website = requests.get(f'https://www.sosubaru.com/new-inventory/index.htm?start={start}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.text, 'html.parser')
    
inventory_count = soup.select("span.d-none.d-sm-inline")[0].string
    
print(inventory_count)
```

This code returns the following:

```
Started OR_GP_Roe_Motors web scrape...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/mypath...", line 16, in <module>
    inventory_count = soup.select("span.d-none.d-sm-inline")[0].string
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then I checked to see why I was getting that error code by returning everything that the soup.select gave me:

```py
inventory_count = soup.select("span.d-none.d-sm-inline")
print(inventory_count)
```

which returned:

```
Started web scrape...
[]
```

Why is it giving me an empty list?

I then told it to print out every span tag on the website to see if it was there. The result printed out many span tags but didn't include the one I am looking for. Why can't I detect it with beautiful soup? Is it the parser I am using? I tried using 'lxml' as the parser but it didn't change anything. Does it have anything to do with the fact that the website is an html xmls doc?

I have already scraped a few websites and haven't had any problems like this until now.

Comment: It's pretty likely that the total count element is populated by a some javascript. So it's not actually exposed in the html that requests returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data and tag you want don't appear in the html source, which means they are being added by javascript. You can either use selenium to get the page source after it has been rendered or you can use requests_html, which has an API similar to BeautifulSoup and it has the option to render a page's javascript before scraping it.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)
r.html.render()
r.find . . . [whatever you want to search for]
```

Comment: Thank you, Eric. This really helped. I found the documentation for this. 
https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/